# Nested object listing with conditions

Tags: python, django

I'm still new to django and it surprised me that I haven't found satisfying answer, but anyway.

I have following model structure (for ordering food every day):

```
# Extended user profile
class UserProfile(models.Model)
# One day - daily menu
class OrderingDay(models.Model)
# One menu (there
class MenuItem(models.Model)
    date = models.ForeignKey(OrderingDay, null=True, blank=True)

# One user ordered something during the day
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    date = models.ForeignKey(OrderingDay)
    item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem)
```

There are some menus that are changed every day (for example *Chicken soup* is available only on Monday, `MenuItem.date = not null`) and some meals (*Hamburger*) that are available every day (`MenuItem.date = null`).

And I just want to list all orders that currently logged user made:

```
Monday:
     Hamburger
     Chicken Soup

# Nothing on Tuesday - skip

Wednesday:
    Meatballs
```

I'm able to filter `OrderingDays` when user has made an order:

```
class CurrentOrdersListingView(generic.ListView):
    model = OM.OrderingDay
    context_object_name='ordering_days'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OM.OrderingDay.filter(order__user=self.request.user)\
               .distinct()
```

But I was unable to google how to list `orders` (I found about [following relations backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)) with reused filter.

How can I achieve following syntax for template:

```
{% for od in ordering_days %}
<h2>{{ od.date }}</h2>
    {% for item in od.items_by_current_user %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can't you just use a `DateField` in you `Order` model?

Comment: @Germano it's possible, but this way it's easier to manage weekends and so on.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get why you have a `date` field on your `MenuItem` model. Can you show us some more of your models code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django helps you create most common queries without needing to resort to raw SQL. Actually figuring out how to translate what you want to what Django needs you to write down can be tricky. The **most helpful thing to remember** when trying to make a query: start the query with what you want.

If it is Orders that you want, you should query for Orders (instead of OrderingDay objects like you're doing in your example).

So you want a user's orders? Something like `Order.filter(user=self.request.user)`.

Ah, but you want those orders grouped by day? Easiest is to first simplify the query output by adding a `.values()` to it: ``Order.filter(user=self.request.user).values('date', 'item')`. This returns a simple list of dicts:

```
[{'date': 'date 1',
  'item': 'hamburgers'},
 {...},
 {...}]
```

Then you can use the ['regroup' template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) in your template. Regroup by `'date'` in your case.

Alternatively, you can do it in code. To your `CurrentOrdersListingView` class, add a `items_per_day()` method with something like this:

```
def items_per_day(self):
    ... your custom grouping code ...
    ... return ['date 1': [item1, item2, item3],
                'date 2': [item2],
                ...
```

And simply call that method in your template:

```
{% for date, items in view.items_per_day %}
  <h2>{{ date }}</h2>
  ....
 {% endfor %}
```

(Methods on a view class are available as `view.method_name` in the template automatically).

---

*Here's the solution that was used in the end:*

You can select all `Orders` using:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return OM.Order.objects.order_by('date__date')\
           .filter(user=self.request.user)
```

And then use `regroup` (it is able to work with model objects perfectly) with sort:

```
{% regroup ordering_days|dictsort:"date.date" by date as ordering_items %}
{% for ordering_day in ordering_items %}
    <h3>{{ ordering_day.grouper.date|date:'l' }}</h3>
    {% for oi in ordering_day.list %}
        {{ oi.item.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```